# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (n^\alpha+m^\beta)^{-s}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\alpha,\beta>0$.

**My question:** What is the infimum $s_0$ of all $s>0$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (n^\alpha+m^\beta)^{-s}$$
converges?

**Upper bound:** I've found out that $s_0 \le \max(2/\alpha,2/\beta)$:
We have
$$n^\alpha+m^\beta \ge 2 n^{\alpha/2}m^{\beta/2}.$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (n^\alpha+m^\beta)^{-s} \le 2^{-s} \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s\alpha/2} \sum_{m=1}^\infty n^{-s\beta/2} = 2^{-s}  \zeta(s\alpha/2)\zeta(s\beta/2).$$
So for the latter series to converge we must have $s>2/\alpha$ and $s>2/\beta$.

**Lower bound:** We have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (n^\alpha+m^\beta)^{-s} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^\alpha+1)^{-s} \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^\alpha+n^\alpha)^{-s} = 2^{-s} \zeta(s\alpha).$$
So we get $\max(1/\alpha,1/\beta) \le s_0$.

Answer (score 2):

One way of approaching this would be to introduce
$$ r_{\alpha, \beta}(x) = r(x) = \# \{(n,m) \in \Bbb N : n^\alpha + m^\beta = x\}$$
and denoting $X = \{x \in \Bbb R : r(x) \geq 1\}.$

For sufficiently large $s$, this directly gives
$$ \sum_{n,m \in \Bbb N} (n^\alpha + m^\beta)^{-s} = \sum_{x \in X} r(x) x^{-s} $$

Note that $X \cap [1,N] \ll \#\{(n,m) : \max(n^\alpha, m^\beta) \leq N\} \ll N^{\frac 1\alpha + \frac 1\beta},$ and we also have the trivial bound $r(x) \ll x^{\min(1/\alpha, 1/\beta)}.$ Using these bounds, we obtain

$$\sum_{x \in X \ \ N/2 < x \leq N}r(x) x^{-s} \ll N^{\gamma - s}  \quad \text{for } \gamma = \frac 1\alpha + \frac 1\beta + \min(1/\alpha, 1/\beta),$$ which directly gives absolute convergence of the series for $\Re s > \gamma.$

However, we can even bound the prior sum assuming $r(x) = 1$ for every $x \in X$ at the cost of $\varepsilon$ in the exponent! We do this by, after being given a pair $N, \epsilon > 0$, choosing $\alpha - \varepsilon < \alpha' < \alpha$ and $ \beta - \varepsilon < \beta' < \beta$ such that $r_{\alpha', \beta'}(x) = 1$ for every $x \in X_{\alpha', \beta'} \cap [1,N]$.
The details are a bit tedious, but I can evaluate if there is need.

For every $\varepsilon > 0,$ this gives the improved bound
$$\sum_{x \in X \ \ N/2 < x \leq N}r(x) x^{-s} \ll N^{\gamma - s + \varepsilon} \quad \text{for } \gamma = \frac 1\alpha + \frac 1\beta,$$
which gives absolute convergence for any $s \in \Bbb C$ with $\Re s > \frac 1\alpha + \frac 1\beta.$
This is optimal at least for $\alpha = \beta = 1,2.$ I would expect this to be optimal in any case, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ natural numbers in your considerations? For me they are real.

Comment: for me they are real as well :)

Comment: Independent of your proof I just showed that the related integral converges iff $s>1/\alpha + 1/\beta$. So I believe your result!

Comment: Ahh, bounding the related integral seems a lot smarter. :D Could you post your result as well?

Comment: Sure, but one still has to argue that the integral converges iff the sum converges.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard. Just replace the inner sum by the integral (which gives an upper bound), interchange summation and integration and replace the inner sum with the integral (which gives an upper bound as well).

Comment: I added my integral as answer. I did it quickly, so a few steps can of course made more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (n^\alpha+m^\beta)^{-s}$$
is related to the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty (x^\alpha+y^\beta)^{-s} dx dy.$$
Using substitution one sees for $a>0$
$$\int_0^\infty (x^\alpha+a)^{-s} dx = a^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-s} \int_0^\infty (x^\alpha+1)^{-s} dx.$$
The latter integral exists iff $s>1/\alpha$. Let's say
$$C_s := \int_0^\infty (x^\alpha+1)^{-s} dx.$$
So in the case $s>1/\alpha$ we have
$$\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty (x^\alpha+y^\beta)^{-s} dx dy
\le \int_1^\infty \int_0^\infty (x^\alpha+y^\beta)^{-s} dx dy\\
= C_s\int_1^\infty (y^\beta)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-s} dy.$$
This integral converges iff
$$\beta(\frac{1}{\alpha}-s)<-1$$
which is equivalent to
$$s > \frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}.$$